# Shearing Stress in a Beam with Torsion

Tags: beam

In "Theory of Elastic Stability" by Timoshenko and Gere, the authors say for a beam in pure torsion,

> For a beam of thin-walled open section it can be assumed with
> reasonable accuracy that the shearing stress at any point is parallel
> to the corresponding tangent to the middle line of the cross section
> and is proportional to the distance from that line.

What is meant by the "tangent to the middle line"? A cross section would be a two dimensional shape. For an I-beam, it would be the shape of an I. But I can see two reasonable definitions of what a middle line could be, since an I has two axes of symmetry. And even then, I'm not sure what a tangent to the line is, other than the line itself.

Comment: I beam is not a thin walled open section.  By thin walled open section, it may mean a pipe or a hollow rectangular stock, or similar entity with a hollow interior surrounded by a relatively thin wall.  Middle line is the middle of the thin wall- halfway between inside and outside.

Comment: What is your understanding of "tangent"?

Comment: @Abel I found this Wikipedia article, which includes I beams among thin walled open sections https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_walled_beams#:~:text=A%20thin%20walled%20beam%20is,%2Dbeams%2C%20and%20so%20on. I now think it means a beam whose cross section can be approximated as the welding of one dimensional curves, but is not topologically equivalent to a circle.

Comment: Maybe an I beam is, although I thought open meant hollow and open to outside at both ends.  Either way middle of the wall is what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The figure indicates a thin-walled open section and the thickness $t, \ $ and the tangent to the midline.

'

[image: figure]

Answer (score 0):

I found a manuscript https://s28490.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/asm-B840.pdf that clarifies the situation.

[image]

The "middle line" mentioned in the quote is not strictly a mathematical line, but may be a curve, or in the case of an I beam or T beam, a join of more than one line segments, which describes the shape of the cross section if the width of the walls were shrunk down to zero.